# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 4} {1-\sqrt{x}} = -1$

Tags: limits

$\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 4} 1-\sqrt{x} = -1$

I'm completely stuck with this, I can't correlate epsilon with delta in this particular case

EDIT : I finally managed to finalize this beauty

It follows:

$|1- \sqrt{x} - 1|<\epsilon$

$|- \sqrt{x}|<\epsilon$

$|\sqrt{x}|<\epsilon$

$|\sqrt{x}| |\sqrt{x}|<\epsilon |\sqrt{x}| $

$|x| < \epsilon |\sqrt{x}|$

$|x-4| < \epsilon |\sqrt{x}| -4$

${|x-4|\over |\sqrt{x}|} + {4\over |\sqrt{x}|} < \epsilon$

Considering $\delta$ as 2, we have

$|x-4| < 2$

$2<x<6$

$\sqrt{2}< \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{6}$

then, ${1\over |\sqrt{x}|} < {1\over |\sqrt{2}|}$

after that I manipulated the equations, and got this:

$|x-4| < \epsilon \sqrt2 - 4$

and then I took $ \delta = min  { (2, \epsilon \sqrt2 - 4) }$

Comment: Please, edit your question to fix the formatting and show us what you attempted so far.

Comment: To complement @ClementC.'s comment: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find out how to write math in your posts. You should also have a look at our [guidelines for asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @ClementC. |x-4| / |√x +2| < €   and that's it, not sure what to do after this

Answer (score 4):

I tried this approach, but I'm not sure it's 100% correct.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary, $f(x)=1-\sqrt x$ and $\delta = 2\epsilon$.

$$|x-4|<\delta \implies |(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt x+2)|<\delta \implies |\sqrt x -2|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt x + 2}<\frac{\delta}{2}$$

But $|\sqrt x-2|=|2-\sqrt x|=|f(x)-(-1)|$ and so $$|f(x)-(-1)|<\frac{\delta}{2} = \frac{2\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

which concludes the exercise

Comment: This looks good.  You might want to bound $\delta$ above by $4$ so you don't ever let $x$ be negative.

Comment: I think we don't need that, we're working in the domain of $f$, that's a closed interval $[0,+\infty[$...